# Prevent part of plugin loading in another menu

Tags: plugins, customization, css

[image: Screenshort of the menu that shuld not be there]

[image: Screenshort of the menu that shuld not be there]

I am trying to remove this part from the menu, my appologie buy im not sure how to take and copy the code from Inspection menu. I do hope this is enough for someone who knows how to. I was thinking maybe i can use custom css to prevent this part from loading. I have noticed if i Deactivate plugin HivePress the menu dissapears. Other than that im not sure how to disable it.
Thank you

Comment: If it is from the menu, see if you can find the menu items in Appearance > Menu section. If not and the menu is created via a plugin, you should try the plugin support. They can help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it out with css code

`.hp-menu__item { display: none; }`